# A fairly simple riddle: When is 90 greater than 100?

Tags: riddle

Here's a fairly simple riddle:
When is 90 greater than 100?
(And it's *not* when you're on the negative side of the number line. Although it is true, it is not the answer)

Comment: Related: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/when-does-11-3

Comment: I think this is clever, but I think it falls prey to the "too many possible answers" close reason :( sorry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some joke answers here and some more serious ones too.

> Rotate 180 degrees, 06 is larger than 001
>
> In roman numerals, XC has more letters than C
>
> The sum of digits is larger for 90.
>
> 90 (in decimal) is greater than 100 (in binary).
>
> **The most common answer:** Enter 90 in a microwave, is 90 seconds while entering 100, is 1 minute or 60 seconds
>
> **Heres an original answer**: In an isoceles triangle, the largest area is when one of the angles is a right angle.  So an isoceles triangle with 100 degree angle is lesser than one with a 90 degree angle.
>
> **Heres an original answer, part 2**: The colour #000090 (dark blue) is brighter (greater in luminosity) than #000100 (very dark green)

Comment: You got it :) The 'most common' one was the one I was thinking of.

Comment: I looked at this question and immediately thought of the "original" answer above. :)

Answer (score 10):

From a programmer's perspective:

> In lexicographical order.
>
>  In Python: `90 > 100` → `False`.
>  But compare as strings, and you get `"90" > "100"` → `True`.

Explanation:

> In lexicographical order, like in a dictionary, you compare characters sequentially.
>  So to check whether `"def" > "abc"`, you first check whether `"d" > "a"` (which it is, because it's later in the alphabet).
>  Because it is, you don't have to check the rest of the string.
>
>  The same holds when you treat numbers as characters. To check `"90" > "100"`, first check whether `"9" > "0"` (which it is, because it's a larger number/later in ASCII).
>  So you immediately conclude `True.`

Answer (score 3):

More joke/serious answers.

> 90 isn't larger than 100, but it is *greater* than 100. Just look at it. Those smooth prime factors. So great.
>
> In base 8, '90' isn't well-defined, but morally it's larger than 100.
>
> In Ruby: `class Fixnu­m; def >=(other) true end end; print 90 >= 100 # prints "true"`